# Transfer a local file to a remote server(windows) using python

Tags: python, paramiko

Hi I have this sample path "\10.81.67.162"  which is a remote server (windows OS)

I want to be able to transfer files (local) to the remote server using paramiko in python.

I can make it work if the server is in linux.

This is my sample code

```
import paramiko
import base64
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
host = "10.81.67.162"
port = 22


transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
stfp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

But having thhis error in windows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 9, in <module>
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 289, in __init__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machi
ne actively refused it
```

Python version 2.7

Paramiko version 1.7.5

Thanks!

Comment: Check the windows firewall settings on the server?

Comment: firewall is off :( @TomDalton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SSH server running on Windows. Thats why you are not able to connect.
Windows doesn't support SSH natively. You need to install third-party SSH server on your remote windows hosts like cygwin, bitwise ssh or freeSSHD.

Or if you are interested to run only commands on windows host then you can use winrm protocol which is natively supported by Windows. For this  you need a python library pywinrm. I have used this and works fine:

https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a network drive, you can use win_unc:

```
import os
from win_unc import UncCredentials, UncDirectory, UncDirectoryConnection

creds = UncCredentials('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
unc = UncDirectory(r'\\<computername>\c$', creds)

conn = UncDirectoryConnection(unc)
conn.connect()

print list(os.listdir(r'\\<computer_name>\c$\<folder>'))
```